What is backfilling when generating an AR sequence?
I am reading this paper: Extracting cycles from Nonstationary Data
I wish to recreate the Monte Carlo simulation in this paper.
I have a query prior to doing this.
On page 8, there is footnote 9, where the author says:

We backfilled $ \epsilon_t $ using 100 observations. This is to ensure that innovation sequence is consistent with the AR(1) generating mechanism.

I did not follow. Can someone please explain to me how to do this ? What exactly is backfilling ?
Here is how I can generate an AR1 sequence similar to the one in the simulation in the paper, of length=216 and autoregressive parameter =.34, using the R programming language:
arima.sim(model =list(ar=.34,order=c(1,0,0)),n=216)

How do I backfill ? Can someone please help me ?
Edit following discussion with mlofton:
Is this how we backfill with a 100 observations??
backfilled.time.series <- c(arima.sim(model =list(ar=.34,order=c(1,0,0)),n=100),
arima.sim(model =list(ar=.34,order=c(1,0,0)),n=216))

or perhaps :
backfilled.time.series <- arima.sim(model =list(ar=.34,order=c(1,0,0)),n=216,n.start=100)

Query : How is backfilling different to generating a longer time series, and ignoring the initial part of the series (which I think is called the burn-in period)?
Edit 2 after reading mlofton's initial response on backfilling:
# Assume that the series to be generated has unconditional mean = 0 and unconditional variance = 1

Here are the IID values as suggested by mlofton
initial.values = rnorm(100,1,0)

backfilled.time.series = arima.sim(model =list(ar=.34,order=c(1,0,0)),n=216,n.start=100,start.innov = initial.values))


It just means to generate iid random variables with zero mean and variance equal to the unconditional variance of the AR1 model. This is one way of dealing with the fact that an AR(1) series needs to be initialized in some way because, in the real world, the earliest data point is $y_1$ rather than $y_{-\infty}$. Note that the unconditional variance of an AR(1) is equal to $\frac{\sigma^2}{(1-\phi^2)}$.

The link didn't work for me but hopefully the AR(1) doesn't have a non-zero mean because, if it does, then the backfilling should be done using this non-zero mean in additional to the unconditional variance. It also wasn't clear if $\sigma^2$ was given or needed to be estimated. But hopefully why one backfills is more clear now. You don't want the initial values in the series to have a distorting effect on the series. This can happen because, in an AR(1), the value of an observation at time $t$ is related to the value at time $(t-1)$ and we don't have a value at time $(t-1)$ when $(t=1)$.

Dear mlofton, my apologies for the link not working. Does this link work for you ? Please see the first result on this link  https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=extracting+cycles+from+nonstationary+data&btnG=&oq=extracting+cycles+from+

Yes. Thanks. It worked. I will print it out but it will take time for me to read it because I don't have much these days. Did you understand my latest comment ? I'm never sure on how clear my explanations are ? But backfilling, as far as I know, is just that: Create say 100 normal random variables with the same mean as the process and the variance equal to the unconditional mean of the process. Attach these to the beginning of the series and they can serve as $y_{(-99)}, y_{(-98)}, \ldots, y_{0}$  in the series. You are basically just making your series longer.

Keep in mind that the long term mean of the process depends on whether the AR(1) has an non-zero mean. Also, note that the the long term mean of say $y_t = \phi y_{t-1} + \mu$ is $\frac{\mu}{1-\phi}$ and not $\mu$.

Last question for now: Are there some pages in that document that are most relevant so I can go directly to those ? Or, if it's best to read the whole thing, that's fine. Thanks.

In the third comment up, I have a bad typo. The third to last line of that comment should read "and variance equal to the unconditional variance of the process". NOT mean.

Dear mlofton, I understand better now with your new explanation. Please allow me some time to digest what I just read.

Hello again, the monte carlo simulation is section 4 of the paper. In that paper the author only gives a fleeting reference to backfilling. He does not explain much.

Dear mlofton, Please see the footnote 9 on page 8 of the paper which refers to backfilling.

okay. I'll check out those sections. Thanks.

I read the pages upto there but my answer doesn't change. what I think they are doing is just attaching 100 normal rv's with those characteristics ( the unconditional variance and mean zero ) to the beginning of the series. The thing that's a little odd is that they don't say what the variance of the process is ? They have to be using some variance for the generation of that AR(1) ?  The only other thing I can think of doing is emailing the author and asking him what they use for the variance in the AR(1) ?

Note that if you google using "backfilling a time-series", the results talk about using it to dealing with missing values. In your case, I'm 99.99 percent sure that this is not what it's being used for.

Dear mlofton, can you show me a paper / book from where you learnt about backfilling?

@mlofton Can you please look at the Edit 1 and 2 in my original query. Is that how you would implement backfilling in R ?

Hi user2338823:  It's probably discussed somewhere in some book but I don't know of one. I think I learned the idea from something said on stats.stackexchange ? I'll try searching on crossvalidated but I may not find it so you may want to look there also.

user2338823: I like the edit 2 approach compared to edit 1 but, even for edit 2, you aren't using the correct unconditional variance. It's whatever the variance is ( which the paper failed to mention ) divided by (1 - ar(1) coefficienct squared). I think the best thing to do would be to email the author(s) and tell them that you are working on reproducing the results in their paper but they didn't provide the variance for $g_t$ in the AR(1) model.  I find that authors are happy to answer questions patticularly when it's someone reading one of their papers !!!!!!

Note that they are using the term "backfilling" but, like you, I really think of it as a burn-in issue.  I could be totally off here because the term backfilling is very vague but I have a strong belief that they are handling burn-in just as you said.

This is pretty related to what we discussed but it's still not what I was looking for. Somewhere on cross-validated there are threads discussing this more directly.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/471518/why-run-the-filter-longer-than-needed-and-remove-the-initial-values-will-solve/471656#471656

@mlofton I wish to award the bounty to you but you have replied only in the comments. I think we can only award the bounty to replies.

Thanks for your effort. I made an answer which is mostly just a copy of one of the comments. It's really not an answer because the paper, IMHO, doesn't provide enough information so don't worry about it. An interesting experience regardless.

Oh, as I said previously, email the author about the whole backfilling issue. He might be glad to respond. And, if he doesn't, there's no loss on your end. Good luck

Note that, I did read pages 1-8 somewhat carefully and for me to have hope of understanding that paper, I would need the one that it's kind of based off of (the one they reference throughout the paper ). But that previous paper is independent of the question(s) we have. Those questions ( why backfill, why is $\epsilon_t$ N(0,1) etc ) are currently not clearly addressed and the previous paper won't help with those either.

I read the pages the footnote but my answer doesn't change. What I think they are doing is just attaching 100 normal rv's with those characteristics ( the unconditional variance and mean zero ) to the beginning of the series.
Notice that I was mistaken about $\sigma^2$ not being specified. $\epsilon_t$ is specified as N(0,1) so $\sigma^2 = 1$ but I don't see how they can just claim that unless it's irrelevant to the construction of $\sum_{t} g_{t}$ ? The only other thing I can think of doing is emailing the author and asking them why they use $\sigma^2 = 1$ for the variance of $\epsilon_t$ in the AR(1) process ? The generation of the backfilled $\epsilon$ would still be done as I explained but it seems like N(0,1) was just pulled out of thin air ?
